# Nested property assign in xstate?

Tags: state, state-management, xstate

I know that you can use the `assign` action creator like this:

```js
const setFoo = assign({
  foo: (context, event) => "someValueBasedOnContextAndEvent",
});
```

But can you use it like this?

```js
const setFoo = assign({
  foo: {
    bar: (context, event) => "someValueBasedOnContextAndEvent",
  }
});
```

Of course, without deleting all other nested values of `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Kourship (creator of xstate) [answered](https://spectrum.chat/statecharts/general/nested-property-assign-in-xstate~9bf323ca-92d2-437c-9fba-df540587d5ca) this on Spectrum:

> No you cannot, but you can make a custom assign function that does that.

So we basically have to create a custom reducer that selectively updates only one field in a nested object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this:

```
const setFoo = assign({
    foo: (context, event) => {
        ...context, 
        foo: {
            ...context.foo,
            bar: "someValueBasedOnContextAndEvent"
        }
    },
});
```

This you will replace the `foo.bar` value, with the desired value and `context` and the rest of `context.foo` remain unchanged